# Oracle database to android

Tags: android

```
android to oracle db:

public class OracleActivity extends Activity{
private Connection con;
protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
try{
connector();
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("not connected"+e);}
public void Connector() throws ClassNotFoundException{
try{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
System.out.println("oracle jdbc driver loaded ok.");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:karthi/xxxx@198.162.12.11:1521:biodata");
system.out.println("connected to biodata@198.162.12.11");
con.close();
system.out.println("sucessfully connected");
}
catch(SQLException e){
System.out.println("not connect oracle db"+e);}
}
}

am also add ojdbc14.jar file and and user-permission: added
Failed resolving Loracle/jdbc/xa/OracleXAResource; interface 265 'Ljavax/transaction/xa/XAResource;'
```

Comment: in that coding not connected to oracle db show exception in log_tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Oracle ojdbc14.jar doesn't contain the interface `javax.transaction.xa.XAResource`.  You also need to add the JTA JAR.  You can find it [here](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/transaction/xa/XAResource.html).

Awful looking code, by the way.  Inconsistent naming and case, ugly syntax.  Here's how I might write it:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class OracleActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:karthi/xxxx@198.162.12.11:1521:biodata";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "scott";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "tiger";

    private Connection connection;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            this.connection = createConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName(driver);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    public static Connection createConnection() ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        return createConnection(DEFAULT_DRIVER, DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have Google installed on your machine?  Please tell me what size spoon you need to be fed with.  See link added above.

Comment: If you keep getting ClassNotFoundException, keep adding JARs until they go away.  Then you'll be left with fixing your code.

Comment: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleRuntimeLoadBalancingEventHandlerThread$1) that doesn't come with anassociated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by acompiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended ******say that expection at the time of uploading jta.jar****solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorr